# Powershell Increment Global:counter++

Tags: xml, powershell, counter, increment, utf

My counter seems to add this very odd char when i just want to replace: '®' with a number according to the counter.

Code:

```
   [int]$global:counter = 1
Get-Content "C:\Users\mikejoh\Desktop\Cases\Sup\sup.xml" | Foreach {
    [regex]::replace($_, '®', 
        {($global:counter++)})
} | Out-File "C:\Users\mikejoh\Desktop\Cases\Sup\sup_test.xml" -encoding UTF8
```

Before Script:

```
<ExternalIdentifier>600®</ExternalIdentifier>
```

Result after:

```
<ExternalIdentifier>600Â1</ExternalIdentifier>
```

What is going on here with that 'Â' char ?

Comment: This has to be an encoding issue...... If the file is UTF8 perhaps you need to _read it in as that_ as well. `Get-Content "C:\Users\mikejoh\Desktop\Cases\Sup\sup.xml" -Encoding UTF8`

Comment: Looks like a possible encoding issue.  Might be unfixable due to how the regex engine works.  [This blog](http://code.logos.com/blog/2008/07/net_regular_expressions_and_unicode.html) says that .Net regex works against "UTF-16 code units and not code points".  Maybe try converting from the source encoding to UTF-16, then applying your regex, and then converting back to UTF-8?

Comment: @Matt reading it with the same encoding worked !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are writing back to file with UTF8 my assumption is that is how the file is encoded and should be read just the same.

I believe that [`Get-Content`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847788(v=wps.620).aspx) defaults to ASCII encoding. Starting with PowerShell 3.0 the `-Encoding` parameter was available.

```
Get-Content "C:\Users\mikejoh\Desktop\Cases\Sup\sup.xml" -Encoding UTF8
```